# Use userform with Checkboxes to create an array in a single cell VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, filter

I trying to use checkboxes in a userform to create an array in a single cell and then use that cell to filter a table with an Array as the Creteria. My code works if one value is input into the cell but once I have more than one value in the cell the filter does not work. I could use some help.

This is the code I am using to input the values into cell A2 in my TestSettings workbook:

```
Private Sub SubmitSettings_Click()

'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim contr As Control
Dim arrType As String


'ACTIVATE SETTINGS WORKSHEET AND FIND FIRST CELL IN COLUMN A
Workbooks("TestSettings.xlsm").Activate

'LOOP THROUGH CHECKBOXES
For Each contr In SettingsForm.Controls

    'CHECKS IF CONTROL TYPE IS A CHECKBOXS
    If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
        
        'CHECKS IF VALUE IS TRUE
        If contr.Value = True Then
            
            'COMBINE VALUES INTO SINGLE STRING SEPERATED BY ,
            If arrType = "" Then
                arrType = contr.Caption
            Else
                arrType = arrType & "," & contr.Caption
            End If
            
        Else
            Debug.Print "False"
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next contr
 
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = Array(arrType)

End Sub
```

This is the code I am using to filter the table i want to filter in my TestProject workbook:

```
Sub FilterTypes()
    'DECLARE VARIABLES
    Dim arType As Variant
    
    'ACTIVATE SETTINGS WORKBOOK
    Workbooks("TestSettings.xlsm").Activate
    
    'SET VALUES
    arType = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
    
    'ACTIVATE TESTPROJECT WORKBOOK
    Workbooks("TestProject.xlsm").Sheets("Project").Activate
    
    'FILTER BY TYPE
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ProjectTestTable1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=Array(arType), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

If cell A2 = A the filter works
If cell A2 = A,B the filter does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ProjectTestTable1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=Split(arType,","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```